# What is best method to reproduce parked page like behavior in IIS7 + ASP.NET

Tags: iis-7, hostheader

I have created parked page like behavior in the past by adding many host headers for different domains to one IIS7 website entry and changing the content of the pages dynamically. I'm wondering if their isn't a different or better way to handle so many domains pointing to one codebase. Is their any limit on the number of host headers for a website in IIS7? Does it affect performance or stability by having so many host headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I have to answer this one myself...

I can say with certainty now that IIS7 will handle serving many hundreds of host headers pointing to the same website codebase. We've been running a setup like this for the better part of a year and it performs well. You can write a script to import the host headers from a CSV file, then turn around and import them into your database.